# Automated unit tests build and run on commandline with Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I'm working on a project with multiple Unit Tests. I have a visual studio .sln file with around 10 XXPrj in it. Those projects are made with Google Test. Everything works well if I want to run them using Visual Studio 2019, I can build and run the unit tests.

I would like to know what is the best way to run them an automated way with commandline. Purpose is to then integrate this commandline stuff in a jenkins to have everything automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Build

Building a Visual Studio solution/project through the **command line** is done with `msbuild.exe`. It works best to add the **path** of **MSBuild** to the `PATH` environment variable.

MSBuild is usually installed somewhere in the Visual Studio folders. E.g. on my machine the path is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Build the solution containing all your projects as follows:

```
msbuild.exe Example.sln

# Or if you want to build a release version or add additional arguments
msbuild.exe Example.sln /property:Configuration=Debug
```

See [MSBuild CLI Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) for more options.

*Side Note:* Jenkins has a [msbuild plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/) you can use with a build step called "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild" *(Important: this does not install MSBuild, it only provides a GUI to use MSBuild in a build plan)*.

### Run Tests

To run the tests you have two options:

- Run each project's executable in your build pipeline and the executable's exit code will indicate the success/failure of the unit tests for that project. However, you will need to call each executable separately; or
- Use the `vstest.console.exe` in combination with the **Google Test Adapter**

You can use the **Google Test Adapter** the same way in which Visual Studio uses it when you click `Test -> Run -> All tests` to discover & execute tests in your projects.

In my environment, `vstest.console.exe` is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
```

You also need to provide the path to the test adaptor. Then execute all the tests as follows:

```sh
# Assuming vstext.console.exe is included in the PATH
# and the current working directory is the relevant project executable
# output folder:
vstest.console.exe Project1.exe Project2.exe Project3.exe /TestAdapterPath:"<path to adapter>"
```

Once again the path is hidden somewhere in the Visual Studio Folders. I found it through searching for `GoogleTestAdapter.TestAdapter.dll`. On my machine it is located in:

```sh
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\drknwe51.xnq
```

### Conclusion

Thus, an automated way to build and run GoogleTest unit tests, which are split over multiple projects, with the commandline can be performed in these two steps:

1. Build the solution/projects using `msbuild.exe`
2. Run the tests using `vtest.console.exe` in combination with the Google Test Adapter

Comment: thanks, works :)